# Javascript turning JSON string into instance of function

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a bunch of JSON string returned from an ajax call in a specific format and when starting to convert them all into my own Javascript object, I start to wonder if there is any easier way since we're talking Javascript here.

I'll have `var manyOfThem = [ { name: 'a' }, { name: 'b' }, { name: 'c' } ];`
And I'd like to easily associate each of these objects with my functions so that I can do things like:

```
myClass.prototype.doSomething = function() {
  // do something to this.name
};

$.each(manyOfThem, function(index, item) {
  item.doSomething();
});
```

I guess my concern is, I would not want to (because its repetitive) do this:

```
var myClass = function(item) {
  this.name = item.name;
  // do the same for the rest of item's potentially 20 properties
};

var oneOfThem = new myClass(manyOfThem[0]); // I think this is redundant....
oneOfThem.doSomething();
```

Anyhow, if there is also (security?) reasons why I'd just have to suck it up and do them all manually please share as well, thanks!

Comment: I think it depends on what you want to in `doSomething`. Can you share what your plan is? Like why couldn't you just make a `function` called `doSomething` and pass `item` to it?

Comment: You could always have `myClass` accept an array (`manyOfThem` in this case). Then, when you want to manipulate one of its items (calling some `doSomething` function), you could do `myClass.doSomething(3)` meaning the 3rd index. Then internally, it would just operate on the 3rd item in the array (without exposing the array).

Comment: @ian Well, it really could be anything, and if `doSomething` was a function outside anything it would be 1. in the global namespace, 2. counter-object-oriented design

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mean, something like (see [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kr5L5/)) :

```
var MyClass = function() {};
MyClass.prototype = {
    doSomething: function() {
        alert(this.name);
    }
};
```

Then

```
var manyObj = $.map(manyOfThem, function(obj) {
   return $.extend( new MyClass(), obj );
});
```

So you can call :

```
manyObj[0].doSomething();  // alert("a")
```

However, this approach will not preserve a direct copy with the `manyOfThem` object. (In the example above, changing `manyOfThem[0].name = "foo";` will not affect `manyObj[0]` and a call to `manyObj[0].doSomething();` will still alert `"a"`. To preserve a direct reference to your object, do this :

```
var manyObj = $.map(manyOfThem, function(obj) {
    function F() {};
    F.constructor = MyClass;
    F.prototype = obj;
    $.extend(F.prototype, new MyClass());
    return new F();
});


manyObj[0].doSomething();  // alert("a")

manyOfThem[0].name = "foo";  // modify the referenced object

manyObj[0].doSomething();  // alert("foo") ..also modifies the behaviour of the instance
```

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot, I think the extend function is the key I am looking for. But for preserving a direct reference to my object, can I confirm with you that the prototype will also contain instance variables such as `this.name` and _can_ be copied over into `F.prototype` altogether?

Comment: Yes, any function or property that is defined will be copied unto the object. For instance, cloning an object is done using : `var clone = $.extend({}, sourceObj);`. In this case, `F.prototype` act as a anonymous class level function constructor to create new prototypes using your `manyOfThem` objects as templates, then extending them with new instances of `MyClass` (so they each have individual scopes).

Comment: I'll have to be honest and say I still don't quite get the concept of object instance properties being copied into a `prototype` but guess whatever the semantics do, that is what it does. Thanks a lot for your answer!

Answer (score 2):

One solution without using a class is

```
var manyOfThem = [ { name: 'a' }, { name: 'b' }, { name: 'c' } ];

function doSomething(){
    console.log(this.name)
}

$.each(manyOfThem, function(index, item) {
  doSomething.call(item);
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/En8hR/1/)

If you want to create an instance of type `MyClas` then

```
var manyOfThem = [ { name: 'a' }, { name: 'b' }, { name: 'c' } ];

function MyClass(item){
    $.extend(this, item);
}

MyClass.prototype.doSomething = function(){
    console.log(this.name)
}

$.each(manyOfThem, function(index, item) {
    var obj = new MyClass(item);
    obj.doSomething()
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/En8hR/2/)

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
var myClass = function(item){  
    for( i in item){  
        if (item.hasOwnProperty(i)){
            this[i] = item[i];
        }
    }
};
```

This should reduce the repetitive assignments in `myClass` constructor.